# Base64 clipping images from database PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, base64, clipping

I am making a website that displays games from a database made in MySQL workbench. I want to have images appear next to the relevant game title of said game. The problem I am having is that I am inserting these images into my database using BLOB and converting them to base64 within the PHP. When I do this and run it, the images come out clipped.

This gets the information from the table that I created in MySQL

```
function find_all_games(){
    global $db; //Connects to database
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM game';
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    return $result;
}
```

This is the table that pulls the information that I want from the database and converts the blob to a base64 image, but the images appear clipped.

```
'<?php while($game = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_all_games)) {?>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><?php
                echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($game['image']).' "height="301" width="220" />'; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="title"><?php echo $game['title']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="title">Released:</td>
      <td class="data"><?php echo $game['release_date']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="title">Publisher:</td>
      <td class="data"><?php echo $game['publisher']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

'

The image should appear just fine but comes out with a white clip on the bottom that changes for each image even though they are all the same size in pixels.

[Evidence that the images display, but are clipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtgG0.png)

Comment: A blob datatype has a max size of 64K. Images are often larger than this so change the datatype to mediumblob (16mb)

Comment: Oh my goodness, I removed that because I had tried something with that before and it wasn't working, but added it back in just now and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much, Jeff. you are an absolute lifesaver!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who had the same issue as me:
Courtesy of Jeff (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2417483/jeff), I was just being silly, and it turned out all I needed to do was make it a MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB depending on the file sizes of your images.